# Can Flash applications have a Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, flash

How is the interaction between these two worlds in a browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at least if you're using ActionScript - see [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html). From that page:

> The ExternalInterface class is the
>   External API, an application
>   programming interface that enables
>   straightforward communication between
>   ActionScript and the Flash Player
>   container– for example, an HTML page
>   with JavaScript. Adobe recommends
>   using ExternalInterface for all
>   JavaScript-ActionScript communication.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at [Swiff in Mootools](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/Swiff) and at digitarald [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/) project which explains the question.